# Carregando data em formato milissegundo no angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Preciso carregar no `input type="date"` datas que estão guardadas em valores em formato milissegundo.

**Exemplo**

```
<label>Data de expiração:</label>
<input  class="form-control" type="date" name="dataexpiracao" ng-model="PontoRelevancia.dados_Evento.dataexpiracao | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' ">
```

Quando uso este filtro usando o  `input type="text"` ele consegue colocar no formato desejado , mas usando o `input type="date"`ele **não funciona**.

O que posso fazer para carregar a informação da data em milissegundo usando o `type="date"` ?

Comment: Já testaste `new Date(PontoRelevancia.dados_Evento.dataexpiracao)`?

Comment: @Henrique acredito que  o format está correto veja esse [exemplo](http://embed.plnkr.co/akLekgX7b1rcaMg6B9rI/) , mas e igual ao autor da resposta disse , temos que converter para datatype que ele aparece lá de boas =|

Comment: @Sergio sim ! testei aqui na minha função de recuperar a informação ele funcionou também mas o ideal e usar a diretiva mesmo para preservar o formato original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa implementar, neste caso, uma diretiva que preserve o formato original, ao mesmo tempo que converte o valor para um datatype que possa ser utilizado com `input type='datetime-local'`.

Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('epochDatetime', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        // transforma o modelo para um tipo Date().
        return new Date(value);
      });
     
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        // converte o valor Date do modelo para milissegundos pós-epoch.
        return value.getTime();
      });
    }
  };
})
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.dataReferencia = 1496268000000;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="dataReferencia" epoch-datetime id="exampleInput"/>
    <pre>{{dataReferencia}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou top obrigado !

Comment: @stringnome sempre um prazer ajudar!